# Call Javascript from HTML component

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML component and a javascript function:

```js
function calculateTime(date1, date2) {
  return date2 - date1;
}
```

```html
<span>calculateTime(date1,date2);</span>
```

But this just results in the actual text 'calculateTime()' with the two dates in between.
How do I escape the text and make sure that the function is called?

Comment: You cannot use JavaScript between tags. You can attach the function call to an event on the element or call by tag name, class, or id in the script.

Comment: You need to invoke the function - Try http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_events.asp - onLoad and Unload events.

Comment: what sort of result are you expecting from subtracting two dates? The number of days, months years between the two? The current code will just return an integer, e.g. -994343229

Comment: Well the thing is, I can't really set the ID because I am using an external tool that fills a table with information from a database. I just give it the name of the database table and it will be automatically filled with the information from that table.

Comment: without an id or some way of identifying the cells, it is going to be tricky to set the content. Is there a larger HTML snippet you could share?

Answer (score 0):

You can't automatically just add a javascript funciton name into html and expect it to run - like you've found, the browser interprets it as text. A way to achieve your desired function would be to add an id to the span, and add this to your js:

```
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = calculateTime(date1,date2)
```

e.g.:

```
<script>
function calculateTime(date1, date2)
{
return date2-date1;
}

document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = calculateTime(date1,date2); //note that we need to SET date1 and date2 before this will work. 

</script>
<html>
<span id="time">calculateTime(date1,date2);</span>
</html>
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/34qL46z3/1

Answer (score 0):

Use as mentioned below:

**HTML:**

```
<span id="calculatedTime"></span>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById('calculatedTime').innerHTML = date2-date1;

}
```